# CASE WHEN...INTO - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, case

is there any way to do a CASE WHEN INTO Statement?

```
Create or replace procedure example
AS
 Variable1 varchar;
 Variable2 varchar;

BEGIN
    Select (CASE WHEN number = 1 THEN
                This_thing INTO Variable1
            ELSE
                That_thing INTO Variable2) The_Other
    FROM table;
END;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We cannot get two outputs from a single CASE() statement.  The best you can achieve is having two separate calls with mutually exclusive conditions:

```
create or replace procedure example as

    variable1 t69.this_thing%type;
    variable2 t69.that_thing%type;

begin
    select (case when whatever = 1 then
                this_thing 
            else
                null 
            end )   
        ,  (case when whatever != 1 then
                that_thing
            else
                null 
            end )   
    into variable1, variable2        
    from t69;
end;
/
```

Comment: (case when whatever != 1 then
                null
            else
                that_thing 
            end )

Comment: this whould replace to whatever=1

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can so:

```
declare 
 Variable1 varchar2(30);
 Variable2 varchar2(30);
BEGIN
    Select decode(dummy,'X','This_thing'),  
           decode(dummy,'X',null,'That_thing')
    INTO Variable1,Variable2
    FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: Two INTO clauses does not a valid query make